# pagebreak if only 1/4th of the page left?

Tags: page-breaking

I have a document with some tabulars one after the other.  I want the tabulars begin on a new page if there is very little room left on the actual page, like 1/4th.  Otherwise, there should not be a pagebreak.  So I need some kind of conditional \pagebreak, how can I do this?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The [`needspace`](http://ctan.org/pkg/needspace) package is very useful for that. Write for example:

```
\needspace{.25\textheight}
\begin{tabular}
...
```

If there's not enough space as requested, approximately, a page break would be inserted. There's further a command `\Needspace` which is exact but less efficient. A starred version `\Needspace*` works flush bottom instead of ragged bottom which is the behavior of the non-starred command.