# Is there a way to know where a line in the .tex file will be whether in the top or the bottom of a page?

Tags: page-breaking, page

I wanted to automatically pass to a newpage when i'm near the end of one on special occasions and so i was wondering if they were anything that would tell where it should be based on what is above. Exactly i would like something giving either the distance to the upper border of the page or the purcentage of advencement in the page.

PS: If you have a way to pass to a new page when near the end of one page, i will gladly accept it even if it doesn't match the rest of my question

Thanks for your answers

Comment: `\the\pagegoal` gives the expected total height of page box, and `\the\pagetotal` gives the accumulated total height of vertical boxes. Related question: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/4017/79060

Comment: if I understand well how \pagegoal keep the height where Latex try to break the page and \pagetotal the current height is that it ?

Comment: @ajreckof: You can use [`needspace`](//ctan.org/pkg/needspace) which inserts a page break if the amount of space is less than a certain amount. That is, you "need a specific amount of space on the page", or else insert a page break. See [pagebreak if only 1/4th of the page left?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/13650/5764) or [How to compute the remaining space on the current page](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/4018/5764).

Comment: Thanks that will do the trick

Comment: @ajreckof Not exactly. This relates to the pagebreak algorithm that tex use. The book [_TeX by Topic_](http://mirrors.ctan.org/info/texbytopic/TeXbyTopic.pdf), chap. 27 gives a detailed explanation.

Comment: Just for the sake of completeness,  `\pagrebreak[3]` can make  a  page break conditional to page break depending of page penalties. In practice, you will see that is rarely used and less of `[3]`  will be ignored in most scenarios and [4] is mandatory, so ....

Comment: @Werner Do you want to change your comment into the answer that I would have given if you hadn't got there first?